# Can't provide 50 point bounty

Tags: support, bounty

According to [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), one can award a bounty of 50 points:

> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned
>   reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty...

I'm trying to award a 50 point bounty as an reward for a good answer ([Android APIs and CPU Architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699252/android-apis-and-cpu-architectures)), but 50 points is not available in the dropdown. The list starts at 100 points:

[image]

I tried un-accepting the answer (and then re-accepting). I could *not* try to retract to upvote because it is locked.

How do I reward the answer with 50 points?

Comment: On the **very page you link to**, it says: *To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).*

Comment: I am able to see 50 in the bounty dropdown list on that question.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: because you didn't post an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry Martin. I don't know what an *overly promotional bounties* is. I just wanted to reward a guy (or gal) who had specialized knowledge and provided a good answer.

Comment: @jww well.. if you think it's that good enough and given your rep - 100 isn't a big deal, surely?

Comment: Martin - this really speaks to a bigger problem. The site makes it hard to immediately reward a good answer. For example, even if I could select 50 points, then I still could not award it immediately. Perhaps there should be a *Reward* (for good answers) in addition to a *Bounty* (for unanswered questions). Then, I could award another without all this hoop jumping an aggravation. The bounty system has screwed up rewards for me in the past, too. Its not just this question.

Comment: The bounty system is "advertising" at the foremost... it may be that the answer you wish to reward now, attracts attention and gets an *even better* answer... that's why the delay, and why you're not immediately able to reward them

Comment: @Jon - actually no. I would prefer to double the points for him or her. That means I wanted to give 25, not 50. But I was willing to provide 50 to work within the system. Now there's another impediment that means I have to provide 100. That's 4x beyond what I would like to provide.

Comment: @ Jon - I don't mean to be disrespectful, but I'm not interested in how Stack Overflow would like me to say my "thank you". I'd like to say it how I see fit without the aggravations.

Comment: Giving more points to an answer doesn't improve the answers visibility in any way shape or form. I don't see any point in creating a bounty for a question that doesn't need more visibility.

Comment: @Kevin - answer visibility is not my goal. My goal is to award more points as a "thank you". It serves two purposes. First, it rewards a person who provides a good, timely answer. Second, I *hope* it provides the foundation for the same behavior in the future. I have more Android/NDK questions, and I'd like to get them answered when I can't find documentation (a lot of the finer points are poorly documented and undocumented).

Comment: *"Second, I hope it provides the foundation for the same behavior in the future."* how can it possibly do that? The first purpose i feel is completely pointless/useless, it doesn't help the site, the question, or the answer in any way shape or form. And, if that was the only purpose of giving said bounty, what's another 50 rep?

Comment: *"The first purpose i feel is completely pointless/useless"* - that's fine. Then you should not do it. *"... if that was the only purpose of giving said bounty..."* - I'm not trying to provide a bounty, but I have to use the bounty system because that's all we have. I feel these answers deserve another 25, not 50 or 100. I'm willing to provide 50 because of system limitations. I think 100 points is a bit much for a "thank you".

Comment: I completely agree with @jww philosophy of letting the (new or old) users allow to decide themselves how _they_ wish to reward another persons elegant answer. Its asif you want to donate a charital activity you come in a church and the Nun says: `Sorry, you can only donate 100$ since you already donated 50$ ten years ago! Also you must come back to confirm it in 24 hours! We don't like overly promotional donations!`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are not allowed to post a 50 point bounty to a question that you have posted an answer to.  This is to prevent people from posing 50 point bounties to all of their own answers in the hopes of generating additional rep from upvotes due to the additional attention.  At a minimum you're forced to invest 100 rep.

If you didn't have an answer to that question then you would be able to post a 50 rep bounty.

(The fact that your answer is deleted is also irrelevant; if an exception existed for such cases people could delete their answer, post the bounty, then undelete it.)

Comment: Are you also prevented from answering AFTER you've posted a bounty?

Comment: @DavidG I do not believe so, no.